# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS MAAS boot fails on fresh install on a Dell 2950

Tags: grub2, dell, maas

I've just installed the latest version of 14.04 LTS on a Dell 2950 (BIOS revision 2.7.0) with a 5TB RAID array, made up of 4, 2 TB SATA drives and the PERC 5/i RAID controller (firmware: 5.1.1-0040).

I installed the Multiple server install with MAAS, using this server as the primary MAAS server.

The installer detects the drive without an issue, and there are no problems on installation, but when I boot the new OS for the first time, I get the following GRUB error:

```
attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0.
```

I've previously installed Debian 7.4 on this disk with no issue whatsoever, and even deleting all the previous partitions before re-installing Ubuntu has failed to change anything. I haven't been able to coax GRUB into loading the operating system from the disk either.

Your help in diagnosing and fixing this problem is greatly appreciated.

Edited to add: Here also is a screenshot of my efforts to manually load GRUB from the disk. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but honestly? The Ubuntu installer should have this right off the bat.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Grub supports EXT4 filesystems in 14.04.

What's the partitioning scheme on the virtual disk from this install versus what Debian installed?  Are you letting the installer handle the partitioning?  If so, what does it look like?

Ideally, you want to boot this machine in EFI mode if it's capable of doing that, but, I don't think that the 2950's support EFI.  If you have to stick with BIOS mode, pay attention to how the disk is partitioned, as you may need to do some manual partitioning work to get the system to boot.  Here's some other info that might help:

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/w/wiki/2837.hdd-support-for-2-5tb-3tb-drives-and-beyond.aspx

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using the basic, guided partitioning that creates a 1MB /boot partition in sda1, a 5TB / partition on sda2, and a swap partition on sda3.

Comment: And no, the 2950s don't support EFI.

Comment: The cause of this was the default GPT partitioning of the boot partition. I re-installed Ubuntu with an old BIOS-style /boot partition, made it bootable, and then finished the install. The server now boots normally.